# ostringstream to vector<uint8_t>

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I've a strange error: I want to copy the content of an ostringstream into a vecotr of unsigned chars:

```
vector< uint8_t > buffer;
ostringstream os;
os << num1 << char1 << num2 << char2;

// 1. this will crash
buffer.insert( buffer.end(), os.str().begin(), os.str().end() );

// 2. this also crash
copy( os.str().begin(), os.str().end(), back_inserter( buffer );

string str = os.str();

// 4. this work 
buffer.insert( buffer.end(), str().begin(), str().end() );

// 5. this also works
copy( str().begin(), tr().end(), back_inserter( buffer );
```

I can't understand why 1 and 2 crash on visual studio 2010.

Does someone has some suggest?

**EDIT**

The solution is:

```
vector< uint8_t > buffer;
ostringstream os;
os << num1 << char1 << num2 << char2;

const string& str = os.str();

// 4. this work 
buffer.insert( buffer.end(), str().begin(), str().end() );
```

Comment: If you want `unsigned char`, why does the code use `uint8_t`? They're not the same.

Comment: they are the same and is defined under <cstdint>

Comment: No, they are not the same. `uint8_t` doesn't exist on platforms that do not have 8-bit unsigned types. `unsigned char` exists on all platforms.

Comment: They are not *necessarily* the same.  With most compilers, they are.  If they were not the same, you could do `void f(uint8_t){} void f(unsigned char){}` but that may not be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
os.str().begin()
```

returns a new **temporary** string with the contents of `os`. You take an iterator to the beginning of it.

```
os.str().end()
```

returns **another temporary string** with the contents of `os`. You take an iterator to the end of it.

The two iterators are not valid since the temporary strings are out of scope now. In addition the iterators also do not belong to the same sequence (*string here*).

What you are doing is *almost* (*not even considering the dangling iterators*) equivalent to

```
string str1 = os.str();
string str2 = os.str();

buffer.insert( buffer.end(), str1.begin(), str2.end() );
```

Comment: so is this right: const string& str = os.str(); buffer.insert( buffer.end(), str().begin(), str().end() );

Comment: Yes that is valid. The life time of the temporary returned by `os.str()` will be extended to the lifetime of `str`. And you are now comapring iterators from the same sequence, So that should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

`ostringstream::str()` returns a **copy** of the underlying buffer.

In your cases 1 & 2 you call `str()` twice (once for `begin()` and once for `end()`) so each resulting iterator relates to different copies of the buffer. Furthermore, those strings are temporaries so they go out of scope immediately, leaving the iterators "dangling".